# Google+ Hangout Video Call Chat History

Tags: google-hangouts

Is it possible to recover the history of the chat window available during Google Hangouts video call? This is separate from the history of the chat client and is not accessible with the same method I presume.

Comment: I'm not sure with video calls, but I queried my gmail account today and saw hangout chat history in the results. Give that a shot.

Comment: @Wutnaut You mean clicking the Chats section in the inbox?

Comment: Just the regular search box at the top of the page immediately after you login to Gmail. The search result will have the " hangout icon on the right if it's from a hangout chat.

Comment: @Wutnaut Yeah most of the chats have that icon actually I could not reach what I am intended to found.

Comment: I confirm the problem. While in-Gmail Hangout chat history is [visible](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3114297), video Hangout chat history seems to be lost forever once the tab is closed. It is certainly not findable from the normal Gmail search box.

Answer (score 1):

Video Hangouts chat history is lost forever once you close the window, alas.